# React Native navigator with persistent scenes

Tags: tabs, reactjs, react-native

This is a pretty common UX design pattern for apps, and I'm trying to figure out how best to implement this in React Native:

### *Users can switch between navigator scenes without losing their scroll position...*

[image: navigator interaction with persisteent panels]

---

By default, the React [`Navigator`](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigator.html) component wants to re-render each scene when the user switches tabs.  This has two drawbacks:

- For complex scenes, there is a needless delay while the scene re-renders itself.
- When the user returns to a scene (e.g. home page), she loses her scroll position and any interim UX state on that scene (e.g. expanded cells, etc)

### Question: is there a way to persist scenes between navigator changes that avoids re-rendering them?

I'm using the following component layout for my navigator pattern:

[image]

p.s. I know React's flux/routing pattern prefers to re-render the scene because it prefers UX state to be captured entirely in one route state object, but in this case I really want to avoid the disadvantages of re-rendering a panel since it creates a crappier user interface....Instagram is an example of an app which does this seamlessly.

Answer (score 3):

If you are pushing and popping scenes it will re-render them.

To avoid this you can start with all your scenes specified in the Navigator's initialRouteStack property then use the jumpTo(route) method of the navigator to transition between them without unmounting and re-rendering. This should preserve the current state of all the scenes.

Answer (score 1):

> By default, the React Navigator component wants to re-render each scene when the user switches tabs.

Where is this from? I'm using `Navigator` in similar patten, and the secenes is "Persist". I don't know what's wrong because there's no code here (maybe you re-render the `Navigator`?), but seams [react-native-scrollable-tab-view](https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-scrollable-tab-view#readme) would be helpful in your example case.